Garmin RDS file - can't seem to open
I have an RDS file obtained from my Garmin.
I'm not sure how to open it though? Garmin Basecamp doesn't seem to support RDS files, nor does Garmin Express - so is there any thing else I can use to open it?
New to this, so I'm intrigued to see the contents from my scan!

do you mean RSD? its not supported in Basecamp. Homeport was the software that can open this format but is discontinued.  see https://youtu.be/e-JnI3eLku8?si=40GOZH_PyxhAbhEA&t=251
